# how to composite image with given opacity over a background in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I have a `bacground.png` image, let say generated with:

```
convert -size 400x100 gradient:red-blue background.png
```

and some overlay image `text.png`, let's say generated with:

```
convert -size 400x100 xc:none  -box white  -pointsize 20 -gravity center -draw 'font-size 60 text 0,0 "Hello"' text.png
```

I would like to generate `text.png` on top of `background.png` with 
`text.png` opacity set to `30%`.

any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I got it:

```
composite -dissolve 30 text.png background.png -alpha Set out.png
```

Based on [compose dissolve](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#dissolve) usage examples.